# Page's events returns empty array

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

in my app, we're asking users to connect their profile with their Facebook public page so we can save events (e.g. info about concerts) in our DB and display them in calendar in our app. Upon calling {pageId}/events endpoint we are receiving empty list of events. We would like to get list of events created by page. Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/2******4/events?access_token=EAACZA******3IZD
```

on production environment app returns:

```
{ "data": [] }
```

and this page has at least one event and we have page access token.

We have Pages_Show_List & Pages_Read_Engagement permissions approved and we were informed it would be sufficient for our purpose. Could you please help us with solving our issue? Is there anything we need to do to make this feature working?

Comment: facebook is down, no, it's gone.

Comment: @JayPow yup I know, but it is not related to this issue. This issue is persistent since we deployed production app (3 weeks old).

Comment: Still a problem in 2022 with v14. I also get an empty array for Page's Events with real Facebook users. Only Facebook App Admin is able to retrieve Events currently for my case.